# Passwordless linux account converted to Chroot jailed sftp now requires password?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, sftp, chroot

I created a user and did an RSA key exchange for a passwordless connection.  This worked.

I also created a chroot jailed sftp only user.  This also worked.

I then created a third user.  I set up the passwordless connection as above, and then jailed the account.  Prior to jailing, the connection worked without the password.  After jailing, a password is required.  And the jail works.

How can I have a user with both?

PS - I've read that the 2.6 kernel (which I'm using) looks for a 2.4 library which is no longer there, and jumps to password authentication.  But the article did not list either the rogue library nor a solution.

Comment: Have you come across [this](http://sysadmin.circularvale.com/server-config/rsa-authentication-with-chrooted-sftp-authorized_keys-location/) already ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the password prompt means that your public key wasn't accepted, which often means permissions problems on $HOME, $HOME/.ssh, etc. Regardless, you should check the syslog and see why sshd is reporting the error. Use LogLevel INFO in your sshd_config file to get some more helpful log messages.